# Amazon EC2 micro instance image with GNU/KDE ready for use

Tags: amazon-ec2

Anyone could indicates to me if know a image on Amazon EC2 with graphical interface under Linux, configured and ready for use? I would like to test the micro instance.

Comment: maybe you would have more luck posting this on another stackexchange.com site?

Answer (score 2):

I do not have such an AMI pre configured but we did create many images where KDE was installed along with other packages. You may create your own AMI with KDE really quick:

1. Launch a standard RHEL 6.0 (32 bit) instance. AMI is publicly available
2. yum install vnc-server
3. edit /etc/sysconfig/vncservers for the username
4. Login to the Linux server using this username and issue command "vncpasswd"
5. yum groupinstall “X Window System”
6. yum groupinstall “KDE Desktop”
7. service vncserver start
8. replace twm with "startkde" in ~/.vnc/xstartup file
9. service vncserver restart

It takes about 10 minutes to complete all these tasks. You can then connect to the instance through VNC client.

Comment: I created a user, and setup the /etc/sysconfig/vncservers for the username but when I do service vncserver start, it fails =\

Comment: I also did vncpasswd with the password of the user I've created

Comment: Added more details to step#4. Ensure you are login to the linux server using 'username' that is mentioned in /etc/sysconfig/vncserver file. If problem persists, post the complete error message.

Comment: I just used the FreeNX and it works. Thanks Everybody!

Comment: For some reason the above flow didn't work for me. I used this one: http://www.confignotes.com/2011/08/rhel-vnc-server-configuration/